# How to use Navbar vue component in index.html of vue cli project?

Tags: vue.js

I just started using. Vue 2.0 cli. The project directory was created and my index.html file looks like this :

```
<body class="drawer drawer--top">
<header class="drawer-navbar" role="banner" id="navbar">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
 </header>

<div id="app">
</div>
</body>
```

The `Hello` component ( created by Vue cli ) is rendered in `div#app`. But I want to render my `Navbar` component in `header#navbar` . I'm using http://git.blivesta.com/drawer/ plugin for navbar. Using it anywhere but 'header' messes up the navbar. How to implement this feature ?

Comment: Did my answer help Shubham?

Answer (score 1):

The Navbar component needs to be inside of the app div.

What you should do is have a root component to replace Hello.vue called something like App.vue

Inside of App.vue have:

```
<header class="drawer-navbar" role="banner" id="navbar">
  <Navbar></Navbar>
</header>
<router-view></router-view>
```

Then use vue-router to display your other routes, and the header will be sticky on the top of all pages you displayed. Essentially 'App.vue' will be a layout file for your app.